# Unable to Refresh the Angular Datatable after filter?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-datatables

I am using Angular Datatable in my angular 4, I am triggering a function on button click which filter the data, but the table is not updated. Any suggestion?

**HTML**

```html
<button (click)="filterData()">Rerender</button>

<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" id="activity" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead #stickyMenu [class.sticky] ="sticky">
        <tr>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Entity</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = 'let audit of tableFilterData id="audit_{{audit.id}}">
          <td>{{audit.time}}</td>
          <td>{{audit.entity}}</td>
          <td>{{audit.action}}</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

**TS FILE**

```ts
dtElement: DataTableDirective; 

filterData() {
    this.tableFilterData = this.auditDetails.filter((obj) => {
        obj.action == 'Create'; 
    });
    this.rerender()
}

rerender(): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        // Destroy the table first
        dtInstance.destroy();
        // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
        this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share in stackbiltz

Comment: There are some issues in your html file.

Comment: @MukeshKumar can you guide me what is the issue

Comment: I have updated the html code. Also check the browser console after clicking the rerender button. If there is an error in the console then share that too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.filter`'s callback doesn't return any value.

 
Try one of following options (they all return the same result):

```
this.tableFilterData = this.auditDetails.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.action == 'Create'; 
});
```

or

```
this.auditDetails.filter((obj) => (obj.action == 'Create'));
```

or

```
this.auditDetails.filter(({action}) => (action == 'Create'));
```

PS. Seems that your `*ngFor` is missing closing quotation mark:

```html
<tr *ngFor='let audit of tableFilterData' id="audit_{{audit.id}}">
```